# Local regularity for harmonic functions (Laplace's equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I need a local Sobolev regularity result for a smooth solution $u$ of
$$
-\Delta u=0
$$
with the equation satisfied in an open set $U$ (I have no boundary conditions). I know that such a smooth $u$ exists, and I have a potentially useful estimate on $u$ in $H^{-2}(U)$, i.e. the dual space of $H^2_0(U)$, which I want to bootstrap to $L^2(U)$. In other words, I want to be able to claim that
$$
\|u\|_{L^2}\le c\|u\|_{H^{-2}}
$$
(with a constant that doesn't depend on $u$). Is this possible?

If the answer is yes, I would like to have a specific reference that gives this result without requiring too much "translation" from the general to the particular (at present I have an indication that this is true with a pointer to Chapter 7 of Morrey's book on multiple integrals in the calculus of variations, but this is not convincing).

Any help would be much appreciated.

James

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **no**.  Let $\,U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\,$ be some bounded domain satisfying the cone condition, $n\geqslant 2$, *i.e.*, the embedding $\,L^2(U)\hookrightarrow H^{-2}(U)\,$ is compact. The assumption that an estimate 
$$
\|u\|_{L^2(U)}\leqslant c\|u\|_{H^{-2}(U)}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
can hold for all harmonic $\,u\in L^2(U)\,$ with some constant $c>0$ independent of $u$ would imply that the subspace $\{u\in L^2(U)\,\colon\, \Delta u=0\,\}$ be locally compact and hence finite-dimensional, which is definitely wrong.  That is why 
$\,(\ast)\,$ cannot hold for all harmonic $\,u\in L^2(U)\,$ with a constant independent of $\,u$.